# bitcoin-qt not syncing on mac os 10.9

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have been using bitcoin-qt for about 7 months without any problems until a few days ago when I launched it and a message popped up saying I should upgrade. So I did, to bitcoin-qt (v 0.8.5). Now all I get is "Synchronizing with network" (Processed 0 of 250284). I have left it for hours and its not changing. I have checked my broadband speed and Im getting approx 7.5 meg. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue. Instead of deleting blockchain data, I found that you can run the application with commandline arg to reindex and rescan:

```
/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt -rescan -reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use an OSX bitcoin client. It is slow as hell. You may try deleting the blockchain data file, which I believe is in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
```

This should restart the syncing process. Be sure not to delete your wallet.data, and you're good to go!